# Unable to access Entity Framework navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, navigation-properties

I have a class AssetRequest that captures an AssetRequest application. For every AssetRequest application a user can select 1 or more Accessory objects to be attached to that application. I am having trouble accessing the Accessories attached to an AssetRequest instance. This is how I have modelled the data (Database-First) :

AssetRequest

```
public partial class AssetRequest
{
public AssetRequest()
        {
            this.AssetRequestAccessories = new HashSet<AssetRequestAccessories>();
        }
public int AssetRequestId { get; set; }
....
....
        public Nullable<int> DepartmentId { get; set; }
 public virtual Accessories Accessories { get; set; }   
}
```

The Accessories associated with each AssetRequest are saved to a different table with a reference foreign key to the AssetRequestId :

AssetRequestAccessories

```
public partial class AssetRequestAccessories
{
    public int AssetRequestAccessoryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AssetRequestId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AccessoryId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual AssetRequest AssetRequest { get; set; }
    public virtual Accessories Accessories { get; set; }
```

}

To get the actual name of any accessories that may have been attached to an AssetRequest application I have defined AccesoryId (in AssetRequestAccessories ) :

```
public partial class Accessories
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Accessories()
    {
        this.AssetRequest = new HashSet<AssetRequest>();
        this.AssetRequestAccessories = new HashSet<AssetRequestAccessories>();
    }

    public int AccesoryId { get; set; }
    public string AccessoryName { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }          
    public virtual ICollection<AssetRequest> AssetRequest { get; set; }       
    public virtual ICollection<AssetRequestAccessories> AssetRequestAccessories { get; set; }
}
```

In AssetRequest table ***only the AssetRequestId is maintained*** and the AssetRequestAccessories will then maintain any Accesories attached to the application as below :

[image: AssetAccessories]

I cannot seem to find a way of directly accessing Accessories object from a given AssetRequest entry . Tried to use navigation properties but its rightly pointing to an *Object Reference not set to an instance* :

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {           
        var services = db.AssetRequest.Include(d => d.Location).Include(d => d.AssetRequestAccessories).Include(d => d.Accessories).Include(d => d.Department).Include(d => d.RequestType).Include(d => d.EmployeeStatus).Where(d => d.IsClosed==1);
        return View(services.ToList());

    }
```

This is what I am trying to do (not working) ;

```
     @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <h5>  <span class="label label-danger arrowed">@item.RequestReference</span></h5>          
 <table id="simple-table" class="table  table-bordered table-hover">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr>                                                                <th>Accessory name</th>                                                              
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            @if (Model.Count() <= 0)
                                                            {
                                                                <tr> <td colspan="3"> No Accessories found for this Request </td> </tr>
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {                                                          
          foreach (var item in Model)
                                                                    {
                                                                    <tr>                                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssetRequestAccessories.Accessories.AccessoryName) </td>
    }
     </tbody>
    </table>
    }
```

I have tried to use an ***anonymous type with joins*** which I then ***cast to AssetRequest*** but still unsure of the correct implementation :

```
 public AssetRequest GetAssetRequest()
    {         
        var assetreqquest = (from j in appEntities.AssetRequest
                             join f in appEntities.AssetRequestAccessories
                             on j.AssetRequestId equals f.AssetRequestId
                             join d in appEntities.Accessories
                             on f.AccessoryId equals d.AccesoryId
                             select new AssetRequest
                         {
                             d.AccessoryName,
                             j.RequestReference,
                             ...
                             ...
                         });
    }
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Side note, classes shouldn't be named in the plural; EF can cope with you calling your accessory Accessory and having a `List<Accessory> Accessories`

Comment: what flavor (core/not) and version of EF is this? What does "not working" mean?

Comment: So, is this a many:many between AssertRequest:Accessory that is decomposed into a pair of one:many by the AssetRequestAccessories table? If so I would expect your query to look more like `context.AssetRequest.Include(ar => ar.AssetRequestAccessories).ThenInclude(ara => ara.Accessories)` if it were EF core (note the THEN INCLUDE) and a more complicated access of a collection if it were EF6

Comment: @CaiusJard I am using EF6.  I'm not sure about the many:many , however my modelling is one:many for AssetRequests to  Accessories. What can i use in EF6

Comment: If the relationship AR:A is 1:M I don't understand why you have an ARA entity (with a pair of singular ID properties, linking to a single AR and single A ie normally this is the pattern of the middleman table that decomposes a M:M into two 1:M) at all. Why does your AR entity not just have a collection of A?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I see from your data model and its likely intended usage, you want a many-to-many relationship between AssetRequests and Accessories. Hence the AssetRequestAccessories linking table. This is not a *pure* linking table in that you want to also track details like the CreatedOn/CreatedBy so EF6 cannot mask this as a many-to-many without a joining entity. There are two ways EF supports many-to-many, without a joining entity, and with a joining entity. You will often see examples used interchangeably as "many-to-many" but that can be a bit misleading. Both relationships use a joining table, but only one maps that joining table to an entity.

A pure many-to-many would look like this from the EF entities:

```
public class AssetRequest
{
    //  ...
    public virtual ICollection<Accessory> Accessories { get; set; } = new HashSet<Accessory>();
}

public class Accessory
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<AssetRequest> AssetRequests { get; set; } = new HashSet<AssetRequest>();
}
```

This is mapped along the lines of:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AssetRequest>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Accessories)
    .WithMany(x => x.AssetRequests>();
```

You have the option to provide details here about the linking table including the name and respective left and right FK names.

This option only works if the joining table (AssetRequestAccessories) is a pure linking table, meaning it only contains a composite key of AssetRequestId and AccessoryId. (/w FK references to their respective tables) No other columns. It
is simpler to work with since our entities effectively reference each other. EF works out the linking table entirely behind the scenes.

Where you want to provide other columns to the linking table things get a little more complex. Rather than a many-to-many relationship, you actually form more of a 1-to-many-to-1 relationship. In this scenario your entities and mappings need to change a bit:

```
public class AssetRequest
{
    //  ...
    public virtual ICollection<AssetRequestAccessory> AssetRequestAccessories { get; set; } = new HashSet<AssetRequestAccessory>();
}

public class Accessory
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<AssetRequestAccessory> AssetRequestAccessories { get; set; } = new HashSet<AssetRequestAccessory>();
}

public class AssetRequestAccessory
{
    [Key]
    public int AssetRequestAccessoryId { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual AssetRequest AssetRequest { get; set; }
    public virtual Accessory Accessory { get; set; }
}
```

When it comes to mapping the relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AssetRequest>()
    .HasMany(x => x.AssetRequestAccessories)
    .WithRequired(x => x.AssetRequest);
modelBuilder.Entity<Accessory>()
    .HasMany(x => x.AssetRequestAccessories>()
    .WithRequired(x => x.Accessory);
```

Often in examples you'll see these collections named like:

```
ICollection<AssetRequestAccessory> Accessories
```

and

```
ICollection<AssetRequestAccessory> AssetRequests
```

in the respective classes, but I would advise against this as the naming implies these collections contain something they don't. It will often cause confusion down the road with new developers. :)

This means that when you want to get the Accessories for an AssetRequest, you have to navigate through the linking entity.

Where in a pure model you can just go:

```
foreach (var accessory in assetRequest.Accessories)
```

... with the linking entity you need to adjust that slightly:

```
foreach (var accessory in assetRequest.AssetRequestAccessories.Select(x => x.Accessory))
```

Certainly a bit clumsier, but it does allow you to support the CreatedOn/By and any other details that apply to the combination of asset request and accessory.